# Catch the "No device found" error coming in Javascript Adapter for Push Notification Service and store it to a variable

Tags: apple-push-notifications

**FWLSE0227E: Failed to send notification. Reason: FPWSE0009E: Internal server error. No devices found**

This error comes in the eclipse console when i try to  send a push notification from my javaScript Adapter(HTTP Adapter) to a device which is not registered. I am using MobileFirstPlatform(MFP) Server.
I want to catch this error an store it to a variable.